# How to get OneSignal userID?

Tags: java, android, mobile, native, onesignal

How can I get OneSignal userID using their latest 4.0.0 Android SDK release?

Comment: Your edit is okay, but it looks imho still too broad. I suggest to make it more narrow. Now I give you a "leave closed" vote, but if you fixed the question and message to me back, I will give you a reopen.